# Problem with my Angular application and Timezone

Tags: angular, momentjs

I'm working on an Angular 6 application where We handle dates to perform some operations, We select those dates with matDatepicker and We format the dates with Moment.js.

The problem is that the app is not taking the browser timezone, it takes UTC time zone and from my location(Central Time) after 7 PM We can't instruct the application to do operations for the current day because it's 5 hours ahead, so it thinks that is already tomorrow, and it's even worse for the people that uses the app from Pacific Time because for them, the system is 7 hours ahead.

This is how We format the dates, I tried removing utc but nothing changed.

`moment.utc(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

The header response returned 5 hours ahead too, I sent the request at 6:15 PM [Header Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nr5iA.png)

I would like to config the app globally to set from UTC to Mountain Time Zone.
could please anybody let me know how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: moment timezone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple trick to set date at local time is set date again with new Date method and set time also with get time method. This resolves my date and time issue as I am getting issue because of different timezone than database timezone. below is example:

```
let yourDate:Date = new Date(yourDateInString);
yourDate.setTime(new Date().getTime());
```

Let's give it a try and let me know if issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the Browser Timezone and UTC timezone difference by using moment JS

moment().utcOffset() by using this you can judge whether you can proceed on the current date or tomorrow's date

Hope it helps